# datepicker help, how to make the calendar popup?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

i'm using jquery 1.5.1 and jquery-ui im trying to create a simple html page with input field and a button that when pushed a calendar will popup.

Comment: is there a specific error you are getting?  The datepicker does that automatically.

Answer (score 3):

**JS**

```
   $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
            showOn: "button",
            buttonImage: "images/calendar.gif",
            buttonImageOnly: true
        });
```

**Markup**

```
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
```

**Reference**

http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#icon-trigger

Comment: Heh, do you have javascript disabled??